# Calling externally the same Java program multiple times to avoid heap space exceeding, and also affect stats

Tags: java, bash, performance, performance-testing

I'm executing tests trying multiple parameter combinations. Each one must be executed 10 times so that I can get an average.

The code below presents my first attempt, which exceeded Java Heap Space.

```
For (int i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
   System.out.println("Test # " + i);
   method( { 1 } );
   method( { 2 } );
   ...
   method( { 1, 2 } );
   ...
   method( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
}
```

Although the method calls System.gc(), the problem persisted.
According to my friend, the GC calling does not guarantee that the memory would be freed. Once all the methods are in the same "for" level, the compiler prevents that happens.

So, I tried to split my test case, repeating only the same case.

```
for (int i=1; i<=10 ; ++ i) {
    System.out.println("Test # " + i);
    method( { 1 });
}
```

The code produced me execution times very different: for instance, the first elapsed 10 seconds, the second 8 seconds, and from the second till the 10th 6 seconds. Note that it is a significant difference if compared to the first execution time. I need to be precise concerning the execution time.

At last, I decided to run manually, but it requires me to be waiting all the time to start it all over again.

Considering that we have 325 combinations, all executed 10 times, I would restart 3250 times the executing, a tough task, especially considering that I'm hurrying to end this step and so compute the results.

---

It is clear to me that I need something like a shell script that calls the code sequentially.

You guys could help me by suggesting one script (I'm using Ubuntu 18), passing as parameter the combination?

Let me know if it is not sufficiently clear.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Make sure `method()` doesn't have a **memory leak**. That mostly means to make sure it doesn't use `static` fields, and if the method is non-static, make sure all fields are cleared when the method exists (or create new instance for each method call). --- You can also just give more memory to the program using the **`-Xmx`** option when you run it.

Comment: Andreas, the method uses static fields to avoid new instantiations. I'm developing an index.

The method doesn't uses so much memory. The problem is the amount of calls in the same for step.

Comment: But if you're *testing* the methods with various parameters, then each test should start with a clean slate, otherwise you're not doing correct unit testing. And if it doesn't "use so much memory", why are you running out of memory, if not because of a memory leak. Fix the leak and your code will run ok.